# Are all exceptions documented for built in python functions?

Tags: python, exception

The python documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=file#file.write), mentions no exceptions that can be raised during a call to `file.write()`.

Does this mean that the function will not raise any exceptions?  What is the behaviour of `file.write()` in the event of no disk space, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's documented right there at the [top of the section on `file` objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=file#file-objects):

> When a file operation fails for an I/O-related reason, the exception [IOError](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IOError) is raised. This includes situations where the operation is not defined for some reason, like `seek()` on a tty device or writing a file opened for reading.

The reason it doesn't mention the exception for every method is that it's the same exception (`IOError`) for every `file` method error caused by an IO-related reason.

You can find out the type of IOError based on the error number, which can be extracted as follows:

```
try:
    f = open("nosuchfile.txt")
except IOError as e:
    print e.errno
```

These error numbers come from the OS, not from Python. In the above case, it would print `2`, as `No such file or directory` is error 2. `No space left on device` is typically error 28, though it might be OS dependent.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd like to know what the different failure modes are. For example, if I can't write to that file for some reason I would start a new file.  However if I have run out of disk space I would give up all together.  Is there some way of differentiating these failures?